# Laravel Form not Passing Data to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

I am re-making the default registration pages in a Laravel installation, and have the following form:

```
<form method="POST" class="uk-form-horizontal uk-margin-large" action="{{ route('registerbasic') }}">
 @csrf
 <input class="uk-input" id="form-horizontal-text" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Jane" name="first_name">
...more inputs

</form>
```

The route in my **web.php** goes to my Auth\RegisterController:

```
Route::post('/register/basic/create', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('registerbasic');
```

And in my **RegisterController@create**, I have:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['first_name'],
            'lastname' => $data['last_name'],
            'province' => $data['province'],
            'postal_code' => $data['postal_code'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

However, when I click submit form, I'm getting an error saying that no arguments are being passed to the `create(array $data)` function:

[image]

How can I get the data in the form passed to this function properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Request` (Illuminate\Http\Request) object. Laravel provide `Request` class and a set of method to handle the request data. For details you can check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    return User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['first_name'],
        'lastname' => $data['last_name'],
        'province' => $data['province'],
        'postal_code' => $data['postal_code'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

**Note:** It is always good to validate your data before creating it and you also need to specify `protected $fillable = [];` in your `User` model class for [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Thank you again rkj. Had to also add the object in.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why the out-of-the-box create method uses an array instead of a Request object? Because clearly that works too, but when I edited the form, I had to now change it to a request object

Comment: @Vranvs updated answer with link, try it and let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0):

In RegisterController use Illuminate\Http\Request. 
And then you can use Request object.

```
public function create(Request $request){   

    return User::create([
        'firstname' => $request->first_name,
        'lastname' => $request->last_name,
        'province' => $request->province,
        'postal_code' => $request->postal_code,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
}
```